# changing values in vector given a location and condition with R

Tags: r, vector

i'm having trouble manipulating vectors in R.   i have a vector that looks like this:

```
stack <- append(append(rep(0,8),c(1,0,0,0,0,1)),rep(0,6))
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

my overall goal is to the manipulate the vector as such:

*when there is a 1, make the next three values in the vector 1.
*change the original 1 to 0.

so ultimately the vector would look like:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

the second part I can do by:

```
replace(stack,which(stack == 1),0)
```

but I can't figure out how to do the first one efficiently.   any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen when you have two ones one after the other in the original list?

Comment: that doesn't happen in my longer vector, but for this question, i guess overwrite ... thanks!  really tough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` here :

```
c(filter(sx,c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),circular=TRUE))
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: i get errors with this.    no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: @bmk759 - looks like dplyr is interfering with base R `?stats::filter`.

Comment: To be doubly explicit, here is a sure way to override dplyr if, like me, you usually "always" have it loaded:  mav <- function(x,n=5){stats::filter(x,rep(1/n,n), sides=2)}

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible base R option

```
temp <- which(stack == 1)
stack[as.vector(mapply(`:`, temp, temp + 3))] <- c(0, rep(1, 3))
stack
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot!  this works for my example.  i'm struggling to try to apply it to a group by with dplyr, however.   i get arguments imply differing number of rows: 9830, 13.  i tried changing around the parenthesis and nothing seems to work.  let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with regular expressions

```
stack <- paste0(stack, collapse="")
stack <- gsub("1.{3}", "0111", stack)
stack <- strsplit(stack, "+")
```